# Are there any research mentioning the principle of tornados or maelstroms in plasma physics related to fusion?

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering, vortex

There are many different ideas and concepts related to design of fusion reactors and handling plasma confinement, but what about designing one around the principles of a maelstrom or a tornado? Is that something that has been researched? Any benefits as opposed to other reactor designs you think?

Comment: For it to be a good idea, there has to be some reason that it would make the reactor perform better. Tornados are violent and can grind things. They are windy and can dry things. How does that apply to fusion? If not, I wouldn't call it a dumb idea. It is just a thought. Perhaps more thinking would improve it, perhaps not.

Comment: Thanks, fair points!

Comment: There are quite a range of suggestions around. Some include shear flow stabilization of z-pinches, for example, which have at least some similarities to tornados.

Answer (score 0):

A vortex-like structure is required in almost all "mainline" fusion designs. This is used to mix the plasma as it rotates around tokamaks and stellarators, which suppresses various instabilities that would otherwise grow until the plasma hits the walls of the reactor.

In the tokamak they do this by mixing an electrical current into the plasma, creating a magnetic field. That field mixes with the one from the magnets outside the reactor, resulting in a spiral pattern. You can see the result very briefly near the end of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAssKNprOGA) - just before it turns off you can clearly see the twisted path of the plasma.

The stellarator produces the same effect purely through magnets. It uses several sets of external magnets designed to mix together and end up with basically the same design. It is more complex, but proponents say these are offset by the lack of current in the plasma.

So, yes, these are very important in fusion.